# object tools could not be found in blender 2.79

Tags: selection-tools

I am a beginner to blender. I created a uv sphere but I couldn't find object tools for uv sphere in blender version 2.79. I am following tutorial in which version 5 is used.

I searched in all the tools options, yet I could not find the option.

Where can I find this option?

Comment: What do you mean by "object tools"? Ways to modify an object while in "Object Mode"? Are you in "Object Mode", or maybe in "Edit mode"?

Comment: The tools are only available immediately after you add the Sphere. If you preform any other action they go away. Delete the Sphere "X" and add a new one.